# Is SqlServer BCP all or nothing?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, bcp

We have some critical code that relies on the .NET SqlBulkCopy API. Occasionally, this code will fail with the following error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table.`

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160218225142/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/04/s.aspx) suggests that this is a transient, nearly unpreventable error. What I'm wondering is, when this error happens, is it guaranteed that no rows have been inserted (if so, I can simply catch this exception and retry the BCP operation on the .NET side)?

I am using SqlServer 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`SqlBulkCopy Constructor (SqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions, SqlTransaction)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wftd1yfz.aspx) constructor, which takes a parameter for `SqlTransaction`. Under that instance of `SqlTransaction` Bulk copy will perform operation and in case of failure you will have the option of rolling back.

You may also see: [Transaction and Bulk Copy Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk.aspx)

> Bulk copy operations can be performed as isolated operations **or as
>   part of a multiple step transaction**. This latter option enables you
>   to perform more than one bulk copy operation within the same
>   transaction, as well as perform other database operations (such as
>   inserts, updates, and deletes) while still being **able to commit or
>   roll back the entire transaction**.

Comment: Would the TransactionScope class work as well? Also, does putting SqlBulkCopy in a transaction hurt performance?

Comment: Transactions are for data integrity. It may affect the performance for large data set and for smaller data set it may not. You have to try it yourself, but IMO it would effect the performance and the insert time should go up.